# Why was Ginny Weasley named Ginny Weasley?

Tags: inspiration, j-k-rowling, harry-potter

The official publishing company of J.K Rowling named **Pottermore** have revealed (see [here](https://www.pottermore.com/features/etymology-behind-harry-potter-character-names)) that there are/were interesting and well thought etymology of characters in Harry Potter book series. It does not contain however all the characters' names' etymology (including famous Longbottoms, Weasleys etc)

What led Ron's sister name to be **Ginevra Weasley** (Ginny Weasley)?

Comment: The name "Weasley" threw me off like crazy the first time I read Sorcerer's Stone. The names were obviously intended to convey character, and the name "weasel" is not a positive association in my experience. I kept expecting Ron to turn out to be the bad guy. I assume that "weasel" has a more positive connotation to Rowling... or maybe she just liked the sound of it and didn't think past that.

Comment: @JoshuaEngel "The names were obviously intended to convey character" You mean like when there was a werewolf running around and one of the characters first name was a mythological hero who was raised by wolves and his last name was Latin for wolf?

Answer (score 13):

I believe all the Weasleys except Ron were named after either characters from Arthurian legend or historical royalty of England/Albion/Britain:

- Arthur (duh)
- Molly (sometimes a nickname for Margaret or Mary)
- William
- Charles
- Percival
- Frederick
- George
- Ginevra (a form of Guinevere)

Comment: I appreciate your answer. From your answer I am making out that it's your personal deduction. I was looking for some official ones..Do you have any official words or link? Just Curious :)

Comment: @KaranDesai Only links to sites where other fans have noticed the same pattern, which have as much weight as mine. :) It is a fact I am observing. I may deduce that since Rowling was so careful with every other name in her universe, she was equally careful here.

Comment: Yeah you have a point :)

Comment: The Charleses have not been a particularly distinguished bunch.

Comment: @JoshuaEngel what about the numerous kings?

Comment: I mean the English Kings Charles, of whom there were only two (one executed, the other merely unimpressive; a third is unlikely to change that reputation [if he picks that name]). Les Charles français have a considerably more impressive (if somewhat spotty) track record.

Comment: Who did you have in mind for Percival and Frederick? I'm not aware of any English/British royalty by either name (though of course Percival is an Arthurian knight and there are lots of continental kings Frederick). Also worth noting that Fred is apparently his full first name, so you might be able to argue that it's actually a shortening of Alfred...

Comment: Surely a simpler explanation is just that (at least in shortened form - Percy, Fred, etc. rather than Percival, Frederick, etc.) they're all **common English names**? The Weasleys symbolise a down-to-earth family, and this comes out in their down-to-earth names, like Ron and Bill as opposed to e.g. Severus or Draco. They have no connection to royalty, symbolic or otherwise.

Comment: @Micah I specifically didn't say *monarchs* because Frederick was only a prince https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frederick,_Prince_of_Wales but yes, Percival was only a knight and not royalty. I'll edit.

Comment: @Randal'Thor *Ginny* may be common, particularly as a nickname for *Virginia*; her full name, Ginevra, is not (that I'm aware of). And the OP was asking about Ginny in particular.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum her name is ginerva  according to the wiki.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum Sure, but ordinary-sounding names as shortened versions of exotic ones has been A Thing in fantasy writing at least since Samwise Gamgee.

Comment: @Mat Nope, [Ginevra](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Ginevra_Weasley).

Comment: @Randal'Thor Okay, but are there any other characters in the series with such an exotic name who go by such a common nickname? It's been a while since I've read it, but I genuinely don't recall any. Everyone pretty much goes by their names: Albus, Minerva, Severus, Kingsley, Remus, Narcissa, Bellatrix, Lucius, Draco, Regulus, Sirius... in fact, I think it's only the Weasleys who regularly *use* nicknames. If there were a dozen "Sam(wise)" names, I'd go with it.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum Narcissa is called "Cissy" by her sister, and (I may be wrong) is Bellatrix also called "Bella"? [Bear in mind](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/104575/31394) that the people with exotic names tend to be from traditionalist wizarding families, who tend to gravitate towards Slytherin, and so we're less likely to see them referred to by nicknames.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Yes, the two sisters have nicknames for each other, but that's not what I meant. Ginevra Weasley is *only* addressed as "Ginevra" in OOtP for the wedding, IIRC. But find me even one character with an exotic name who *routinely,* to everyone, goes by a nickname. Tonks goes by her last name, not Dora, for example. My original point is that there's no reason for a "down-to-earth" family to give their daughter an exotic name if there isn't some thematic reason (like Arthurian characters/British royalty).